# SyntaxError with Jest and React and importing CSS files

Tags: reactjs, babeljs, jestjs

I am trying to get my first Jest Test to pass with React and Babel.

I am getting the following error:

> SyntaxError: /Users/manueldupont/test/avid-sibelius-publishing-viewer/src/components/TransportButton/TransportButton.less: Unexpected token

```
    >  7 | @import '../variables.css';
          | ^
```

My package.json config for jest look like this:

```
"babel": {
    "presets": [
      "es2015",
      "react"
    ],
    "plugins": [
      "syntax-class-properties",
      "transform-class-properties"
    ]
  },
  "jest": {
    "moduleNameMapper": {
      "^image![a-zA-Z0-9$_-]+$": "GlobalImageStub",
      "^[./a-zA-Z0-9$_-]+\\.png$": "RelativeImageStub"
    },
    "testPathIgnorePatterns": [
      "/node_modules/"
    ],
    "collectCoverage": true,
    "verbose": true,
    "modulePathIgnorePatterns": [
      "rpmbuild"
    ],
    "unmockedModulePathPatterns": [
      "<rootDir>/node_modules/react/",
      "<rootDir>/node_modules/react-dom/",
      "<rootDir>/node_modules/react-addons-test-utils/",
      "<rootDir>/node_modules/fbjs",
      "<rootDir>/node_modules/core-js"
    ]
  },
```

So what am I missing?

Answer (score 144):

`moduleNameMapper` is the setting that tells Jest how to interpret files with different extension. You need to tell it how to handle Less files.

Create a file like this in your project (you can use a different name or path if you’d like):

#### `config/CSSStub.js`

```
module.exports = {};
```

This stub is the module we will tell Jest to use instead of CSS or Less files. Then change `moduleNameMapper` setting and add this line to its object to use it:

```
'^.+\\.(css|less)$': '<rootDir>/config/CSSStub.js'
```

Now Jest will treat any CSS or Less file as a module exporting an empty object. You can do something else too—for example, if you use CSS Modules, you can use a Proxy so every import returns the imported property name.

Read more in this [guide](https://jestjs.io/docs/en/webpack.html).

Comment: I am using Jest v19+ and have the following key value pair in `moduleNameMappers`: `"\\.(css|sass)$": "identity-obj-proxy"`, but, I have some `.sass` files which use the `@import` keyword that makes the transformAndBuildScript function throw. Is there any way to fix this?

Comment: In fact, even with a `sassMock.js` file that just exports an empty object for all `\\.sass$` files, I'm seeing the same error.

Comment: Using `"\\.(css|less)$": "identity-obj-proxy"` worked for me

Comment: @JaKXz how did you solve that problem? I am getting the same problem, I am using css-modules to import css files. You can find more details about the question at: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48286678/css-module-import-fails-the-jest-test-suit?noredirect=1#comment83558957_48286678

Comment: I only had *.scss before, adding *.css also fixed my issues. Thanks.

Comment: I found this very helpful: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54627028/jest-unexpected-token-when-importing-css#comment113260726_54646930

Answer (score 90):

I solved this by using the `moduleNameMapper` key in the jest configurations in the package.json file

```
{
   "jest":{
        "moduleNameMapper":{
             "\\.(css|less|sass|scss)$": "<rootDir>/__mocks__/styleMock.js",
             "\\.(gif|ttf|eot|svg)$": "<rootDir>/__mocks__/fileMock.js"
        }
   }
}
```

After this you will need to create the two files as described below

**`__mocks__/styleMock.js`**

```js
module.exports = {};
```

**`__mocks__/fileMock.js`**

```js
module.exports = 'test-file-stub';
```

If you are using CSS Modules then it's better to mock a proxy to enable className lookups.
hence your configurations will change to:

```
{
  "jest":{
     "moduleNameMapper": {
      "\\.(jpg|jpeg|png|gif|eot|otf|webp|svg|ttf|woff|woff2|mp4|webm|wav|mp3|m4a|aac|oga)$": "<rootDir>/__mocks__/fileMock.js",
      "\\.(css|less|scss|sass)$": "identity-obj-proxy"
    },
  }
}
```

But you will need to install `identity-obj-proxy` package as a dev dependancy i.e.

```
yarn add identity-obj-proxy -D
```

For more information. You can refer to the [jest docs](https://jestjs.io/docs/en/webpack)

Comment: For anyone who arrives here from create-react-app, `moduleNameMapper` is not a supported override. The version is 1.1.4 at the point of the comment.

Comment: I don't use CRA and none of these solutions works. I'm so frustrated :(

Comment: as identity-obj-proxy is old, not sure it should be used or not, but using the stub definitely worked with my webpack react jest project

Comment: This helped me. I didn't use create-react-app and I'm using Parcel instead of Webpack. Thank you.

Comment: a good idea to map these types of files with mock versions. brilliant.

Comment: it works for me with reactLogo with vite app created, thanks

Comment: this seems to be such a common gotcha, I wonder why it would it not make sense to have some zero config defaults that could be overridden

Answer (score 35):

UPDATE who use ***create-react-app*** from feb 2018. 
You cannot override the moduleNameMapper in package.json but in jest.config.js it works, unfortunately i havent found any docs about this why it does.
So my ***jest.config.js*** look like this:

```
module.exports = {
...,
  "moduleNameMapper": {
    "\\.(jpg|jpeg|png|gif|eot|otf|webp|svg|ttf|woff|woff2|mp4|webm|wav|mp3|m4a|aac|oga)$": "<rootDir>/__mocks__/fileMock.js",
    "\\.(scss|sass|css)$": "identity-obj-proxy"
  }
}
```

and it skips scss files and @import quite well.

Backing my answer i followed [jest webpack](https://jestjs.io/docs/en/webpack)

Comment: For me it doesn't seem to work even if I put it in `jest.config.js`.

Comment: In my .storybook/preview.js, I import mui fonts with `import '@fontsource/roboto/400.css'`.
While running the jest script, I had an error `.../node_modules/@fontsource/material-icons/index.css:2
    @font-face {
    ^

    SyntaxError: Invalid or unexpected token...`

To fix it, I added in jest.config.js in moduleNameMapper `'@fontsource': 'identity-obj-proxy',` and it fixed my issue

Comment: @SébastienNOBOUR that should be it's own answer!

Answer (score 18):

Similar situation, installing identity-object-proxy and adding it to my jest config for CSS is what worked for me.

```
//jest.config.js

module.exports = {
  moduleNameMapper: {
    "\\.(css|sass)$": "identity-obj-proxy",
  },
};
```

The specific error I was seeing:

```
Jest encountered an unexpected token

/Users/foo/projects/crepl/components/atoms/button/styles.css:1
({"Object.<anonymous>":function(module,exports,require,__dirname,__filename,global,jest){.button { }
                                                                                         ^

SyntaxError: Unexpected token .

  1 | import React from 'react';
> 2 | import styles from './styles.css';
```

Comment: Worked like a charm (I'm testing a nuxt app with jest)

Comment: Works great. May need to add scss or less as well.

Answer (score 17):

If you're using [ts-jest](https://github.com/kulshekhar/ts-jest), none of the solutions above will work! You'll need to mock transform.

#### jest.config.js

```
module.exports = {
  preset: 'ts-jest',
  testEnvironment: 'jsdom',
  roots: [
    "<rootDir>/src"
  ],
  transform: {
    ".(jpg|jpeg|png|gif|eot|otf|webp|svg|ttf|woff|woff2|mp4|webm|wav|mp3|m4a|aac|oga)$": "<rootDir>/jest-config/file-mock.js",
    '.(css|less)$': '<rootDir>/jest-config/style-mock.js'
  },
};
```

#### file-mock.js

```
module.exports = {
  process() {
    return `module.exports = 'test-file-stub'`;
  },
};
```

#### style-mock.js

```
module.exports = {
    process() {
      return 'module.exports = {};';
    }
  };
```

I found this working [example](https://github.com/hamzahamidi/webpack-typescript-starter/blob/main/jest.config.js) if you want more details.

Comment: Also make sure that you have a types.d.ts file with `declare module '*.scss';` or similar if you still get the Cannot Find Module error.

Answer (score 13):

Solution of @import Unexpected token=:)

Install package:

```
npm i --save-dev identity-obj-proxy
```

Add in jest.config.js

```
module.exports = {
  "moduleNameMapper": {
    "\\.(css|less|scss)$": "identity-obj-proxy"
  }
}
```

Answer (score 4):

Update: Aug 2021
If you are using Next JS with TypeScript. Simply follow the examples repo.

Else you will be wasting days configuring the environment.

https://github.com/vercel/next.js/tree/canary/examples/with-jest

Comment: The link is down. Would you mind updating it, please?

Answer (score 1):

To ensure Jest ignores CSS files when running tests, simply follow the steps below:

**Install a module**

npm install -D identity-obj-proxy

**Update package.json**

```
"jest": {
    "testEnvironment": "jsdom",
    "moduleNameMapper":{
      "\\.(css|less|scss|sass)$": "identity-obj-proxy"
    }
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

I added moduleNameMapper at the bottom of my package.json where I configured my jest just like this:

```
"jest": {
    "verbose": true,
    "moduleNameMapper": {
        "\\.(scss|less)$": "<rootDir>/config/CSSStub.js"
    }
}
```