# React Jest causing "SyntaxError: Unexpected token ."

Tags: reactjs, jestjs, babel-jest

I am now using React Jest to test code. If a component is single, and not importing anything else, "npm test" runs smoothly. Now I want to test multiple components together, and I immediately get this error:

> SyntaxError: Unexpected token .

It seemed whenever React is importing something else, such as this one:

```
require( './style/fixed-data-table.css' );
require( './style/jnpr-datatable.scss' );
```

and then using Jest, it is throwing the unexpected token "." error.

There must be something wrong in my settings, but where? My *package.json* file contains:

```
 "jest": {
   "unmockedModulePathPatterns": [
     "<rootDir>/node_modules/react/",
     "<rootDir>/node_modules/react-dom/",
     "<rootDir>/node_modules/react-addons-test-utils/"
   ]
 }
```

And the *.babelrc* file is already in the root. Also *babel-jest* is included.

Comment: you can try with : **"ignore": ["*.css","*.scss"]** in your .babelrc

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39418555/syntaxerror-with-jest-and-react-and-importing-css-files maybe help

Comment: I used this: {
  "presets": ["es2015", "react"],
"ignore": [".css",".scss"]
}
in babelrc, when run npm test, same error. Any idea?

Comment: Re *"package.json"*: Implying [Node.js](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Node.js)?

Answer (score 41, accepted):

Have a look at the Jest documentation for [Webpack integration](https://facebook.github.io/jest/docs/en/webpack.html). The problem is that Jest can’t work with other stuff than JavaScript. So you have to mock all non-JavaScript files you import. The easiest way is to configure a `moduleNameMapper` in your Jest configuration.

```
{
  "jest": {
    "moduleNameMapper": {
      "\\.(css|scss)$": "<rootDir>/__mocks__/styleMock.js"
    }
  }
}
```

With a `__mocks__/styleMock.js`, that looks like this.

```
module.exports = {};
```

Comment: Smart solution! This is the only one that makes it work. Thanks

Comment: Where can I find: __mocks__/styleMock.js?  Or, if it's something I need to create, under which folder should it be housed?  Sorry if that's obvious, I'm new to jest and I'm currently stumped.  Greatly appreciate the help!

Answer (score 5):

The easiest is to add an `identity-obj-proxy` package:

`yarn add --dev identity-obj-proxy`

And use it to automatically mock CSS/SCSS modules.

Add this to the `package.json`:

```
  "jest": {
    "moduleNameMapper": {
      "\\.(css|scss)$": "identity-obj-proxy"
    }
  }
```

Or the following to `jest.config.ts`:

```
moduleNameMapper: {
  '\\.(css|scss)$': 'identity-obj-proxy'
}
```

This way (S)CSS module class names will be automatically retrieved in tests.

Here is the [source](https://jestjs.io/docs/webpack#configuring-jest-to-find-our-files).

Answer (score 3):

1. `npm i -D identity-obj-proxy`
2. Add the below to file *jest.config.js*

   ```
   moduleNameMapper: {
       "\\.(css|less|scss|sass)$": "identity-obj-proxy"
   }
   ```
3. File *jest.config.js*:

   ```
   testEnvironment: 'jsdom',
   ```

Comment: It's worked for my app. But I don't understand why don't works other answers.

Comment: *Why* does it work? What is the idea? What environment? Please respond by [editing (changing) your answer](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/70368912/edit), not here in comments (but ******* ***without*** ******* "Edit:", "Update:", or similar - the answer should appear as if it was written today).)

Answer (score -2):

The way I got away with this was by adding these two lines to my `.babelrc` file:

```
{
    "presets": ["env", "react"],
    "plugins": ["transform-class-properties"]
}
```

And my [package.json](https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/v9/configuring-npm/package-json/) file looks like this:

```
{
  "name": "crud-redux",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
  "react": "^16.4.0",
  "react-dom": "^16.4.0",
  "react-scripts": "1.1.4"
},
 "scripts": {
     "start": "react-scripts start",
     "build": "react-scripts build",
     "test": "NODE_ENV=test jest",
     "eject": "react-scripts eject"
},
  "devDependencies": {
      "babel-jest": "^18.0.0",
      "babel-loader": "^6.4.1",
      "babel-plugin-transform-decorators-legacy": "^1.3.5",
      "enzyme": "^2.9.1",
      "jest": "^23.1.0",
      "react-addons-test-utils": "^15.6.2",
      "react-test-renderer": "^15.6.2",
      "redux-mock-store": "^1.5.1",
      "webpack": "^1.15.0",
      "webpack-dev-server": "^1.16.5"
  }
}
```

Comment: *Why* does it work? What is the idea? What environment? This answer is currently too terse. (But please *********************************** ***without*** *********************************** "Edit:", "Update:", or similar - the answer should appear as if it was written today).)