# SyntaxError with Jest and React importing SCSS files

Tags: javascript, reactjs, unit-testing, jestjs

I am testing using Jest and my appication is running on Next.js... I am trying to test a page component in my Next application, but I am receiving errors that are shown in the following screenshot; The "Before" image is before I tried implementing a [solution found on Stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39418555/syntaxerror-with-jest-and-react-and-importing-css-files#), and the "After" is after the solution was implemented. I am still stuck and need some friendly help!

[image]

Here is also my current Jest config in my `package.json`

```
"jest": {
  "setupFiles": ["./shim.js", "./setupTests.js"],
  "verbose": true,
  "moduleNameMapper": {
    "^.+\\.(css|scss)$": "./cssStub.js"
  }
}
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I'm using `CSS modules` and it convenient for me to use "proxy" as if the code requires styles, jest will return a proxy, that will return the required field name instead of the value.

For example:

```
import * as styles from './styles.scss';

console.log(styles.someClassName);
// the proxy in that case will return a string with `someClassName` value.
```

All you need to configure is install 
`npm install --save-dev identity-obj-proxy`
and add

```
"moduleNameMapper": {
      "\\.(css|scss)$": "identity-obj-proxy",
}
```

to your Jest section in the `package.json file`.

**Edit**

Pay attention that according to the [docs](https://facebook.github.io/jest/docs/en/configuration.html#modulenamemapper-object-string-string) you should use `<rootDir>`
when you are mapping to a file.
`"\\.(css|scss)$": "<rootDir>/cssStub.js.js",`

Comment: Interesting. Thanks for your answer! However, the project is not using CSS modules, so I’m not sure if this is the solution I’m looking for.

Comment: Edited my answer

Answer (score 0):

My issue was silly enough that I wrongly specified my `<rootDir>` path. I would suggest reading the solution from this post for further details to how to resolve similar issue... Thanks all for the help!

[SyntaxError with Jest and React and importing CSS files](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39418555/syntaxerror-with-jest-and-react-and-importing-css-files)