# CSS module @import fails the Jest test suit

Tags: javascript, reactjs, jestjs, css-modules

I am using Jest and Enzyme to test my application. I am getting error:

```
 FAIL  app/containers/Navbar/NavbarContainer.test.js
  ● Test suite failed to run

    app/components/Navbar/styles.css: Unexpected token (1:0)
      > 1 | @import "../../styles/base/_variables";
          | ^
        2 |
        3 | .navbar{
        4 |   width: $navbar-width;
```

This is my Jest configuration in package.json:

```
"jest": {
    "verbose": true,
    "globals": {
      "env": {
        "isProd": false,
        "isDev": true,
        "command": "start"
      }
    },
    "moduleNameMapper": {
      "\\.(css)$": "identity-obj-proxy"
    },
    "moduleFileExtensions": [
      "js",
      "jsx",
      "json",
      "css"
    ],
    "modulePaths": [
      "/app"
    ],
    "moduleDirectories": [
      "node_modules"
    ],
    "verbose": true,
    "setupFiles": [
      "./setupJest.js"
    ],
    "setupTestFrameworkScriptFile": "<rootDir>/setupTests.js"
  }
```

I was following the guides while setting up the application, and I found that `identity-obj-proxy` will help to mock css-modules functionality, but that's not working in my case. Please let me know what am I missing here.

P.S. this is about not ES6 modules import. The suit failed because there is a `@import` in css.

Comment: @elbecita that question is about ES6 module imports, that can be solved by `babel-jest`. This is about `css-modules`'s `@import`s. If you see the same thing could you please remove the possible duplicate flag?

Comment: Yes, I am sorry, I read too quickly. Might this help? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39418555/syntaxerror-with-jest-and-react-and-importing-css-files The guy has the error because of an @import in a less file, but that really sounds like your issue?

Comment: Basically the solution would be to create an empty module and tell jest that for any css file it should use that empty module instead. (Since "identity-obj-proxy" seems to not be working).

Comment: @elbecita `identity-obj-proxy` is the advanced solution of adding mock files. checkout comments in the answer, the guy solved his problem by using the same plugin.

Comment: Does it work if you include the extension (.css) in the @import statement?

Comment: tried it, it doesn't work with that. Actually the the problem is Jest is not able to understand `@import` in a CSS file. So adding or removing extension for the solution is out of the question.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/163270/discussion-between-elbecita-and-bharat-soni).

Answer (score 5):

UPDATE who use ***create-react-app*** from feb 2018.
You cannot override the moduleNameMapper in package.json but in jest.config.js it works, unfortunately i havent found any docs about why it does the trick.
So my ***jest.config.js*** look like this:

```
module.exports = {
...,
  "moduleNameMapper": {
    "\\.(jpg|jpeg|png|gif|eot|otf|webp|svg|ttf|woff|woff2|mp4|webm|wav|mp3|m4a|aac|oga)$": "<rootDir>/__mocks__/fileMock.js",
    "\\.(scss|sass|css)$": "identity-obj-proxy"
  }
}
```

and it skips scss files and @import quite well.

I added to devDependencies **identity-obj-proxy**

Backing my answer i followed [jest webpack](https://jestjs.io/docs/en/webpack)

Comment: This resolved my issue too. I simply had to change `"moduleNameMapper": {
      "\\.(css|jpg|png|svg)$": "path/to/JestMockModule.js"
    },`  to `"moduleNameMapper": {
      "\\.(s?css|jpg|png|svg)$": "path/to/JestMockModule.js"
    },`. Just 2 character solved my issue.

Answer (score 2):

So, I've found the solution to this problem. I was importing CSS without the extension in my components and Jest was confusing that import with JS file. Solution is instead of importing css like:

```
import * as styles from './styles'
```

you should import it like:

```
import * as styles from './styles.css'
```

Answer (score 1):

I know this post is old but i solved this issue by adding `jest-transform-css` as a devDependency

```
npm i --save-dev jest-transform-css
```

and then adding the following inside `jest.config.js`

```
    transform: {
                '^.+\\.js$': 'babel-jest',
                '.+\\.(css|styl|less|sass|scss)$': 'jest-transform-css'
    }
```

you can refer to this [github issue](https://github.com/facebook/jest/issues/3094) for more information

Answer (score 0):

One quick gotcha that I found with this.  If you have a jest.config.js file, then you need to set your moduleNameWrapper inside of that config file.