# How to mock a css import for jest/enzyme test?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, unit-testing, jestjs, enzyme

I need to mock an imported CSS file in my jest/enzyme test:

**Header.test.js**

```
import React from 'react'
import { shallow } from 'enzyme'
import { Header } from './Header'

jest.mock('semantic-ui-css/semantic.min.css') // <-- no effect...

it('should render page title', () => {
  const wrapper = shallow(<Header title='Test' />)
  expect(wrapper.find('title').text()).toEqual('Test')
})
```

I do get the error for the `import 'semantic-ui-css/semantic.min.css'` line:

```
Test suite failed to run

    /Users/node_modules/semantic-ui-css/semantic.min.css:11
    @import url(https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Lato:400,700,400italic,700italic&subset=latin);/*!
    ^

    SyntaxError: Invalid or unexpected token
```

I don't need import the css file for the test. So I would like to mock that import out for the test. How can I do that?

I tried to do `jest.mock('semantic-ui-css/semantic.min.css')` but that doesn't work.

This is how the Header.js looks like:

**Header.js**

```
import Head from 'next/head'
import 'semantic-ui-css/semantic.min.css'

export const Header = props => {
  return (
    <Head>
      <meta http-equiv='content-type' content='text/html;charset=UTF-8' />
      <meta charset='utf-8' />
      <title>{props.title}</title>
      <link rel='icon' href='/static/favicon.ico' />
      <link rel='stylesheet' href='/_next/static/style.css' />
    </Head>
  )
}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [SyntaxError with Jest and React and importing CSS files](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39418555/syntaxerror-with-jest-and-react-and-importing-css-files)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [ignore-styles](https://www.npmjs.com/package/ignore-styles) package in your jest config.

```
npm install --save-dev ignore-styles
```

In your jest.config.js file include these lines

```
import register from 'ignore-styles';
register(['.css', '.sass', '.scss']);
```

[jest-css-modules](https://www.npmjs.com/package/jest-css-modules) is the another package you can try.

Comment: What do you mean by `jest.setup.js` file? I only have an `jest.config.js`