# Jest encountered an unexpected token in typescript

Tags: css, reactjs, typescript, jestjs, enzyme

I'm testing my React+TypeScript Component, but I'm getting this weird message,
I tried everything but didn't find any helpful resources, is this is the TypeScript error or something else, to be honest, I'm dizzy here, so I came across an issue:

```
Jest encountered an unexpected token

    This usually means that you are trying to import a file which Jest cannot parse, e.g. it's not plain JavaScript.

    By default, if Jest sees a Babel config, it will use that to transform your files, ignoring "node_modules".

    Here's what you can do:
     • To have some of your "node_modules" files transformed, you can specify a custom "transformIgnorePatterns" in your config.
     • If you need a custom transformation specify a "transform" option in your config.
     • If you simply want to mock your non-JS modules (e.g. binary assets) you can stub them out with the "moduleNameMapper" config option.

    You'll find more details and examples of these config options in the docs:
    https://jestjs.io/docs/en/configuration.html

    Details:

    /home/dr/code/npmpackage/darkmode/src/style.module.css:1
    ({"Object.<anonymous>":function(module,exports,require,__dirname,__filename,global,jest){.switch {
                                                                                             ^

    SyntaxError: Unexpected token '.'

      1 | import * as React from 'react'
      2 | // import 'learning-npm-package/dist/index.css'
    > 3 | import classes from './style.module.css'
```

Packages I'm currently using in React Project are below:

```
"peerDependencies": {
    "react": "^16.0.0"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@testing-library/jest-dom": "^4.2.4",
    "@testing-library/react": "^9.5.0",
    "@testing-library/user-event": "^7.2.1",
    "@types/jest": "^25.1.4",
    "@types/node": "^12.12.38",
    "@types/react": "^16.9.27",
    "@types/react-dom": "^16.9.7",
    "@typescript-eslint/eslint-plugin": "^2.26.0",
    "@typescript-eslint/parser": "^2.26.0",
    "babel-eslint": "^10.0.3",
    "cross-env": "^7.0.2",
    "enzyme-to-json": "^3.5.0",
    "eslint": "^6.8.0",
    "eslint-config-prettier": "^6.7.0",
    "eslint-config-standard": "^14.1.0",
    "eslint-config-standard-react": "^9.2.0",
    "eslint-plugin-import": "^2.18.2",
    "eslint-plugin-node": "^11.0.0",
    "eslint-plugin-prettier": "^3.1.1",
    "eslint-plugin-promise": "^4.2.1",
    "eslint-plugin-react": "^7.17.0",
    "eslint-plugin-standard": "^4.0.1",
    "gh-pages": "^2.2.0",
    "microbundle-crl": "^0.13.10",
    "npm-run-all": "^4.1.5",
    "prettier": "^2.0.4",
    "react": "^16.13.1",
    "react-dom": "^16.13.1",
    "react-scripts": "^3.4.1",
    "ts-jest": "^26.1.2",
    "typescript": "^3.7.5"
  },
  "files": [
    "dist"
  ],
  "dependencies": {
    "@types/enzyme": "^3.10.5",
    "@types/enzyme-adapter-react-16": "^1.0.6",
    "enzyme": "^3.11.0",
    "enzyme-adapter-react-16": "^1.15.2",
    "react-test-renderer": "^16.13.1"
  }
```

./style.module.css:

```
.switch {
  display: flex;
  height: 36px;
  position: relative;
  width: 70px;
}

/** small */
.container {
  height: 26px;
  width: 50px;
}
```

**any help will be appreciated, thanks!**

Comment: let me know if you need anything else!

Comment: This `./style.module.css` is also needed. Otherwise, it might be difficult to figure out that is wrong.

Comment: @ikos23 thanks for letting me know, style.module.css contains a lot style  I can't upload all here, I updated the quest!

Comment: I removed my answer as it does not provide an answer :) I wasn't aware of create-react-library which I believe includes support of CSS modules, so your import should be correct.

Comment: Have you tried to rename `switch` class into something different and check if it makes any difference?

Comment: @ikos23 you shouldn't have deleted the question, may someone find it helpful! yeah, I tried but still doesn't work, thanks!

Comment: Check if this helps - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54627028/jest-unexpected-token-when-importing-css?noredirect=1&lq=1

Comment: Also, consider investigating `transform` with `jest-transform-css` [as mentioned here](https://github.com/facebook/jest/issues/3094#issuecomment-431564037).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So, I'm gonna answer it myself after researching found the solution. by default jest don't know how to handle the CSS file, we need CSS module mock for jest, for that, we need to create a bridge between Webpack and Jest, this is how `moduleNameMapper` comes to play the bridge role, we just need to install the `identity-obj-proxy` to create a mock CSS Module that returns the expected CSS className like `<div className={classes.div}>`.

Let's install the proxy:

```
yarn add identity-obj-proxy

// NPM
npm install identity-obj-proxy
```

create a file on root `/` directory not `src`, named `jest.config.js` and put the beneath code:

```
module.exports ={
  moduleNameMapper: {
    "\\.css$": "identity-obj-proxy",
  },
};
```

[Resource](https://medium.com/trabe/testing-css-modules-in-react-components-with-jest-enzyme-and-a-custom-modulenamemapper-8ff86c7d18a2)