# Jest encountered an unexpected token (TinyMCE)

Tags: css, reactjs, unit-testing, jestjs

I'm using `Jest` to run unit tests on one of my components, but I'm getting a few errors.

The component that I am trying to test uses `tinymce` and as a result, I import a few files from tinymce. I've seen on the offical Jest documentation that I insert the following, which I have in my `setupTests.js` file:

```
Object.defineProperty(window, 'matchMedia', {
  writable: true,
  value: jest.fn().mockImplementation(query => ({
    matches: false,
    media: query,
    onchange: null,
    addListener: jest.fn(), // Deprecated
    removeListener: jest.fn(), // Deprecated
    addEventListener: jest.fn(),
    removeEventListener: jest.fn(),
    dispatchEvent: jest.fn(),
  })),
});
```

However, I have done that, but I am encountering another problem:

> Jest encountered an unexpected token SyntaxError: Unexpected token '.'
>
> import "tinymce/skins/ui/oxide.skin.min.css"

I have tried to follow the advice of mocking everything that comes from Tinymce, as well as mocking non-JS modules, using "moduleNameMapper". For example, my `_jest.config.js` file includes:

```
module.exports = {
  "moduleNameMapper": {
    "^image![a-zA-Z0-9$_-]+$": "GlobalImageStub",
    "^[./a-zA-Z0-9$_-]+\\.png$": "<rootDir>/RelativeImageStub.js",
    "module_name_(.*)": "<rootDir>/substituted_module_$1.js",
    "assets/(.*)": [
      "<rootDir>/images/$1",
      "<rootDir>/photos/$1",
      "<rootDir>/recipes/$1"
    ]
  }
  "transformIgnorePatterns": [
    "<rootDir>/node_modules/"
  ]
}
```

The above doesn't work and I still get the same error.

**EDIT:**

As per one of the suggestions, I've created a `styleMock.js` file which contains `module.exports = {};` and is included in my `src/tests/jest/__mocks__` path. I've then inputted:

```
"moduleNameMapper": {
  '\\.(css|less)$': '<rootDir>/src/tests/jest/__mocks__/styleMock.js'
}
```

But I'm still getting the same error as above.

Comment: You haven't included `.css` extensions in the `moduleNameMapper` and jest is trying to import the CSS file as a JS file which results in that error. Maybe one of the answers [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54627028/jest-unexpected-token-when-importing-css) will help

Comment: Thank you. I'm still getting the same error even though I've created a `styleMock.js` which exports an empty object, as well as adding the `moduleNameMapper` in my `jest.config.js` file as the answer suggests. I've edited my question to reflect this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Following this [documentation](https://jestjs.io/docs/webpack#mocking-css-modules) worked.

In another words, adding in the `package.json` the following:

```
{
  "jest": {
    "moduleNameMapper": {
      "\\.(jpg|jpeg|png|gif|eot|otf|webp|svg|ttf|woff|woff2|mp4|webm|wav|mp3|m4a|aac|oga)$": "<rootDir>/__mocks__/fileMock.js",
      "\\.(css|less)$": "identity-obj-proxy"
    }
  }
}
```

As well as running `yarn add --dev identity-obj-proxy`